# How can I delete a specific Cloud Firestore document using the documentID in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, document

[image: Firebase]

I'm using a list to display injury data that the user has inputted via a form, that is successfully added to Cloud Firestore. I now want to add a delete function that deletes the injury selected in the list.

Here is my `Injury` Struct:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct Injury: Identifiable, Codable {
  @DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
  var userId: String?
  var specificLocation: String
  var comment: String
  var active: Bool
  var injuryDate: Date
  var exercises: String
  var activity: String
  var location: String    
}
```

My `InjuriesViewModel`:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

class InjuriesViewModel: ObservableObject {    
  @Published var injuries = [Injury]()
    
  private var db = Firestore.firestore()

  func fetchData () {
    let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    
    db.collection("injuries")
      .order(by: "injuryDate", descending: true)
      .whereField("userId", isEqualTo: userId)
      .addSnapshotListener{ (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
          print("no documents")
          return
        }
                
        self.injuries = documents.compactMap { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Injury? in
          return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Injury.self)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

My `InjuryViewModel` (here is where the add and delete injury functions are, however I'm not sure how to fill in the document field):

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class InjuryViewModel: ObservableObject {    
  @Published var injury: Injury = Injury(id: "", userId: "", specificLocation: "", comment: 
    "", active: false, injuryDate: Date(), exercises: "", activity: "", location: "")
    
  private var db = Firestore.firestore()

  func addInjury(injury: Injury) {
    do {
      var addedInjury = injury
      addedInjury.userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
      let _ = try db .collection("injuries").addDocument(from: addedInjury)
    }
    catch {
      print(error)
    }
  }
      
  func deleteInjury(injury: Injury) {
    db.collection("injury").document(??).delete() { err in
      if let err = err {
        print("Error removing document: \(err)")
      } 
      else {
        print("Document successfully removed!")
      }
    }
  }
    
  func save () {
    addInjury(injury: injury)
  }
    
  func delete () {
    deleteInjury(injury: injury)
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Here's where I'm at:

```swift
  func addInjury(injury: Injury) {        
    do {
      var addedInjury = injury
      addedInjury.userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
      let documentRef = try db.collection("injuries").addDocument(from: addedInjury)
      addedInjury.id = documentRef.documentID
      print(documentRef.documentID)
    }
    catch {
      print(error)
    }
  }

  func deleteInjury(injury: Injury) {
    db.collection("injuries").document(injury.id!).delete() { err in
    if let err = err {
      print("Error removing document: \(err)")
    }
    else {
      print("Document successfully removed!")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't know the document ID, you won't able to delete the document.  You're either going to have to remember it after you call `addDocument` (which returns a DocumentReference), or make a query for the document base don what you know about the contents of its fields in order to get the ID to delete it.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. Would you be able to show me how to go about saving the document reference? I've added a photo of what my firebase looks like and it's not storing the 'id'. Thanks

Comment: You are currently saving the resulting document reference with `let _ = ...`.  What you do with it after that is up to you.  It has a documentID property with the ID of the newly created document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `deleteInjury`, you just need to access the `documentID` of the current `Injury` that your view model holds:

```swift
func deleteInjury(injury: Injury) {
  db.collection("injury").document(injury.id).delete() { err in
    if let err = err {
      print("Error removing document: \(err)")
    } 
    else {
      print("Document successfully removed!")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'm very new to firebase and Swift in general and your videos have been amazing. Really appreciate your help. I'm still not able to save the id in the firebase document. I've updated my functions above

Comment: The documentRef.documentID is printing successfully in the console.

Comment: Can you try using `@StateObject` in your view instead of `@ObservableObject`? I've got the suspicion that SwiftUI is recreating your view model and in the project of doing so destroying the `@Published injury` instance.

Comment: @JoshAllen did this help?

Comment: I'm still yet to update to Xcode 12 and Swift 2.0, I believe I need these in order to use @StateObject. I will update and see if that solves the issue. Thanks so much again!